# How can I get LightDM to work on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, lightdm, login-screen

**Is there a permanent fix for the looping login problem in LightDM?**

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. LightDM won't work even though I haven't changed any options (background, etc.). It just throws another login screen at me if I log in.

So I did the stuff you're supposed to. I reconfigured gdm from the terminal and used that to log in, and have been using gdm for ~3 months now.  The thing is, I want LightDM back so I can change it to a desktop background I made. (I have no idea about customising GDM and really don't care.)

Comment: Is there any chance that tightvncserver package is installed?

Comment: I believe so, I have "X11VNC Server" with a TightVNC option enabled.

Comment: After re-install, problem is mysteriously gone - however, I prefer MDM after all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into recovery mode, selected "network" then "root" and run the following command:

```
# chown -R your_username:your_username /home/your_username
```

Upon rebooting, access to desktop should be reestablished.

Comment: komputes answer fixed the problem for me. More specific: the .Xauthority file in my home directory had root ownership, after changing the ownership to <your_username> the login worked again chown -R your_username:your_username /home/your_username/.Xauthority @komputes: sorry but I cannot upvote and comment due to not enough reputation